flet: работает только одна кнопка
Работает лишь одна из кнопок. Сделал примерный код с кнопками и страницами, куда они должны вести. Работает только третья кнопка
from flet import *


def main_o(page: Page):
    page.title = "TestProject"
    page.theme_mode = 'light'
    page.vertical_alignment = MainAxisAlignment
    page.horizontal_alignment = CrossAxisAlignment
    page.window_width = 385
    page.window_height = 660
    page.padding = 0
    BG = '#FFFFFF'
    ScrollbarTheme = 'dark'

    wallet_page = Row(
        [
            Column(
                [
                    Text("Soon...")
                ],
                horizontal_alignment=CrossAxisAlignment.CENTER
            ),
        ],
        alignment=MainAxisAlignment.CENTER,
    )

    award_page = Row(
        [
            Column(
                [
                    Text("Soon...")
                ],
                horizontal_alignment=CrossAxisAlignment.CENTER
            ),
        ],
        alignment=MainAxisAlignment.CENTER,
    )

    Equip_page = Row(
        [
            Column(
                [
                    Text("Soon...")
                ],
                horizontal_alignment=CrossAxisAlignment.CENTER
            ),
        ],
        alignment=MainAxisAlignment.CENTER,
    )

    climb_page = Row(
        [
            Column(
                [
                    Text("Soon...")
                ],
                horizontal_alignment=CrossAxisAlignment.CENTER
            ),
        ],
        alignment=MainAxisAlignment.CENTER,
    )

    def openpage1(e):
        page.clean()
        page.add(award_page)

    def openpage2(e):
        page.clean()
        page.add(Equip_page) 

    def openpage3(e):
        page.clean()
        page.add(climb_page)

    def openpage4(e):
        page.clean()
        page.add(wallet_page)



    main_page = Container(
        Stack([
            Image(
                src='/images/bg.png',
            ),
            Container(
                width=385,
                height=650,
                # opacity=0.5,
                # bgcolor= BG,
                padding=padding.only(left=0, right=274, top=420, bottom=0),
                border_radius=10,
                content=Row(
                    alignment=MainAxisAlignment.CENTER,
                    controls=[
                        ElevatedButton(
                            on_click=openpage1,
                            width=50,
                            height=50,
                            opacity=0.3,
                        ),
                    ],
                ),
            ),
             Container(
                width=385,
                height=650,
                # opacity=0.5,
                # bgcolor= BG,
                padding=padding.only(left=0, right=136, top=420, bottom=0),
                border_radius=10,
                content=Row(
                    alignment=MainAxisAlignment.CENTER,
                    controls=[
                        ElevatedButton(
                            on_click=openpage2,
                            width=50,
                            height=50,
                            opacity=0.3,
                        ),
                    ],
                ),
            ),
            # Container(
            #     width=385,
            #     height=650,
            #     # opacity=0.5,
            #     # bgcolor= BG,
            #     padding=padding.only(left=0, right=0, top=420, bottom=0),
            #     border_radius=10,
            #     content=Row(
            #         alignment=MainAxisAlignment.CENTER,
            #         controls=[
            #             ElevatedButton(
            #                 on_click=openpage,
            #                 width=50,
            #                 height=50,
            #                 opacity=0.3,
            #             ),

            #         ],
            #     ),
            # ),
            Container(
                width=385,
                height=650,
                # opacity=0.5,
                # bgcolor= BG,
                padding=padding.only(left=274, right=0, top=420, bottom=0),
                border_radius=10,
                content=Row(
                    alignment=MainAxisAlignment.CENTER,
                    controls=[
                        ElevatedButton(
                            on_click=openpage3,
                            width=50,
                            height=50,
                            opacity=0.3,
                        ),
                    ],
                ),
            ),
            Container(
                width=385,
                height=650,
                # opacity=0.5,
                # bgcolor= BG,
                padding=padding.only(left=136, right=0, top=420, bottom=0),
                border_radius=10,
                content=Row(
                    alignment=MainAxisAlignment.CENTER,
                    controls=[
                        ElevatedButton(
                            on_click=openpage4,
                            width=50,
                            height=50,
                            opacity=0.3,
                        ),
                    ],
                ),
            ),
        ])
    )

    page.add(main_page)
app(target=main_o, assets_dir='assets')


Научитесь нормально задавать вопросы. в заголовке - суть вопроса. все остальное - в теле вопроса.

Извиняюсь, впервые задаю вопрос. Спасибо
